DALI addressing
I am using the DALI system in which I use the broadcast method. Now I want to work on individual addressing. I want to know how to start.
In the broadcast method which I am using now, I am using one function. Function syntax is -
App_Dali_Send(uint8_t grp, uint8_t address, uint8_t cmdType, uint8_t databyte)

Here grp = 1, address = 3F, cmdtype = 1 if I am sending commands or else it will be zero if I am sending lamp power, databyte = commands number.
I want to do individual addressing. Can I know the process?

We cannot know how the API you use works to send broadcast or unicast messages. Sending DALI messages isn't necessarily an electrical engineering issue.

When you say you want to "do indivdual addressing" there are two ways this could be interpreted, corresponding to the commissioning process and the operational phase. If the control gears are new, you need to commission them - set the individual addresses, they do not come with these preset from the factory, for this see the Related questions on this page. Then you can send short addressed messages. Once you have individually addressed gear you can set group addresses and use group addressed messages.


Start by reading IEC 62386-102, especially table 1 in section 7.2.1 which explains the address format of 16bit forward frames.
Then, once you understand what a "control gear" is and how the different addressing schemes work, you can proceed by assigning short addresses and/or broadcast groups to your control gear.
Once you have that, figure out how the programming API that you use and the DALI bus master interface that you're accessing via this API work.


how to assign short adress to the control gear

That's a complicated process which is described in IES62386-102. The key part is section 11.7.
